# Possible ways to create this table in angular without using any libraries

Tags: angular

Possible ways to make this nested table in angular 13 with only HTML Table. I've tried many ways but can't figure out how to nest topics and subtopics.

here is the image link of the table **https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugkuS.jpg**

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you has an array with 14 elements. The properties can be
subject,subjectRowspan,topic,topicRowSpan,subtopic,acurrancy,totalCount...

You calcule the properties "subjectRowPan" and "topicRowSpan" to equal to 0,1 or the number of items repeated

```
  <tr *ngFor="let element of elements">
    <td
      *ngIf="element.subjectRowSpan != 0"
      [attr.rowspan]="element.subjectRowSpan"
    >
      {{ element.subject }}
    </td>
    <td *ngIf="element.topicRowSpan != 0" [attr.rowspan]="element.topicRowSpan">
      {{ element.topic }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ element.subtopic }}
    </td>
    ...
  </tr>
```